# Sort an array of variables and assign them the sorted value

Tags: javascript

I use this code to sort table values:

```js
var t1 = 6;
var t2 = 2;
var t3 = 4;
var t4 = 1;
var t5 = 3;
var t6 = 5;

var points = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6];

points.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
```

This returns:  `1,2,3,4,5,6`

This `sort` method works fine but how to updated the sorted values to the variables in that order? Like, least value should be assigned to `t1`, second least to `t2`,...and max value to `t6`?

Comment: `t1 = points[0]; t2 = points[1]; ... ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to assign the sorted values back to the variables:

```js
var t1 = 6;
var t2 = 2;
var t3 = 4;
var t4 = 1;
var t5 = 3;
var t6 = 5;

var points = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6];

[t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6] = points.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b })

console.log(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6)
```

Now, the first value from *sorted array* will be assigned to `t1`, second value to `t2` etc.